# Does Shabbat desecration have a "time duration" factor?

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work

One of my friends told me that when *Kvish Shesh* - "Tollway rte. 6" in Israel was completed, there was some concern about cars driving on the road on Shabbat. The CEO of *Derech Eretz*, the company that manages the road suggested that drivers should speed on Shabbat so that they spend less time desecrating Shabbat.

When I heard this, granted, I was surprised that apparently there was no concern about the safety concerns of speeding on the highway. But, I have also never heard that *chilul Shabbat* involves a "time duration". E.g. if I write a letter on Shabbat, I believe that I have violated a melacha once whether it takes me 3 minutes or hours.

Is there any validity to this notion of lessening the amount of time you are *mechalel Shabbat*?

Comment: "... _there was some concern about cars driving on the road on Shabbat_". More so than on other roads?

Comment: Speeding is probably worse, as I'd suspect the RPM of the engine would increase on average in greater proportion than the speed of the vehicle would increase (i.e., the total number of "fires lit" during the drive could be hundreds if not thousands more if you are speeding or frequently accelerating rapidly). (Edit: I'm talking about a conventional gas powered combustion engine, not an electric car).

Comment: Interesting, what can we compare it to? Is a Melakha discrete or continuous - Nafkah Minah for sacrifice? One who drives a car is he Hayav for every time he pushes the pedal?

Comment: I have heard that it is better not to stop a non-observant Jew in order to cross the street, so that he doesn’t stop and then reaccelerate, burning more gas.

Comment: I have read sources which suggest, for example, giving a non-observant Jewish driver directions so he can take the shortest route and thus minimize Sabbath desecration. I am not sure this concept extends to travelling speed.

Comment: @AlBerko I like your question but unfortunately that nafka mina doesn't work out of the box
https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Shabbat.7.1 https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Nazir.6.4

Comment: In addition, does one who wrote small letters on Shabbos get stoned less severely than one who wrote big letters? IIRC, once a Shiur is met it does not matter at all.